# argument types are:(size_t, const char[2])

Tags: c++

//build a greeting
    const string greeting = "Hello, " + name + "!"; <-- nsme is a string entered in cmd line

```
//build 2nd and fourth lines of the output
const string spaces(greeting.size()," "); <-- getting red line here
const string second = "* " + spaces + " *";

//build the first and fifth lines
const string first(second.size(), "*"); <-- getting red line here
```

I understand what the code is trying to do - ie: set the size - but I'm not sure why this isn't working.
Intellisense had 'size' in the options list after I hit the '.' following greeting and second so I expected this to work. Using VS2013 pro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const string spaces(greeting.size()," ");
```

`std::string` does not have a constructor that can take those arguments.

What do you expect it to do? If you want a string with N copies of a single character you need to pass it a single character, not an array of characters i.e.

```
const string spaces(greeting.size(), ' ');
```

Comment: simply changing from double to single quotes solved the problem. thanks much

Comment: @Bawboc: This situation is like if you're programming a zoo, and all your cages are implemented as `std::vector<Car *>`. Then you can say, "simply changing the type from `Car` to `Animal` solved the problem.

Comment: I don't understand.  Was my reply incorrect? I'm a bit of a noobie so I don't know all the nuances I should use when posting.

Comment: @James: Well, I wanted to point out that the "simple change of quotes" is not all that "simple". It's changing something very fundamental (namely the type and value of an object), and I wanted to caution you against dismissing this as a "simple typo", as your comment suggested. You should really understand the difference. There are other languages, like Bash, where the two kinds of quotes are similar but subtly different and one might make a simple typo, but in C++ it's not like that at all.